# Openerp Login Error

Tags: odoo

I've been getting this error and can't view the user's list and projects/task or even login using the user's login information.

Can anyone help me..

Thank you.

OpenERP Server Error

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 195, in dispatch 
      response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1012, in search_read
     return self.do_search_read(req, model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1047, in do_search_read
     records = Model.read(ids, fields or False, req.context)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 40, in proxy
     result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 28, in proxy_method
     result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 101, in send
     raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.exception_to_unicode(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 87, in send
     return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 361, in dispatch_rpc
     result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 601, in dispatch
     res = fn(db, uid, *params)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 167, in execute_kw
     return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 121, in wrapper
     return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 176, in execute
     res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr
     return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 796, in read
     res = super(users_view, self).read(cr, uid, ids, fields, context=context, load=load)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 272, in read
     result = super(res_users, self).read(cr, uid, ids, fields=fields, context=context, load=load)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3575, in read
     result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)   
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3660, in _read_flat
     record.update(res3[record[col]]) 
KeyError: 3
```

Comment: Give which version you are using ?
Do you have any customization or not ???

Comment: I used openerp v7. I don't have any customization..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a backup of database ,delete the current database and create a new one, later you can import all your data.

Answer (score 1):

Error shows that record for id 3 is not exist in database.

When you try to read the data from database its delete the record which you are trying to read.

Please reconnect and try to open project/task.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to find the error with only that information, but I had several times a Key Error due to a problem updating the openerp server, and after updating again all, the problem dissapeared.

Try to update the module *base* from the user interface, and if that doesn't work, try to restart and update all the openerp server from the console.

Answer (score 0):

if there is any functional field, please check it. This kind of key error will raise in functional fields while returning the values in a desired format.